# grep for x20-x7E regex hex range not working in Windows10 MINGW64 bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep, windows-10, mingw-w64

My file test.csv

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1,AAA,1,
2,BBB,0,
3,CCCÆ,,ttt
4,DDD,1,
5,EEE,0,
```

Expected output:

```
3,CCCÆ,,ttt
```

Tried:

```
grep -a "[^\x20-\x7e]+" test.csv
grep -a '[^\x20-\x7e]+' test.csv
grep "[^\x20-\x7e]+" test.csv
grep '[^\x20-\x7e]+' test.csv
```

also tried the flags -P and -E but all do not return me the result I want.
In Powershell, I did

```
Select-String -Pattern '[^\x20-\x7E]+' test.csv
```

and it returned me the expected result.

Could someone point me in the right direction for MINGW64 bash `grep (GNU grep) 3.1` on Windows10? 
It is installed via git download for windows here: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: `grep -P '[^\x20-\x7E]+'` [returns the expected result](https://ideone.com/8Kis62).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't for my environment. I get the entire file contents as my output.

Comment: Was it installed for Native Windows/i686?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its a standard Windows10 install and MINGW64 is installed via git download for Windows.

Comment: does locale even a thing at ming? ^^

Comment: @Jetchisel ```$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I see, `LC_ALL` is empty, might be silly though but, can you set `LC_ALL=C`

Comment: @Jetchisel `LC_ALL=C grep "[^\x20-\x7E]" test.csv` Tried this and result is the same, entire file is output.

Comment: Aww, worth a try...

Comment: No idea how you got it at all, the MinGW for Windows does not contain `grep`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is installed via git download for windows.

Comment: What is the command?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: I have it, I have no idea how you got MinGW with grep

Comment: The point here is that the hex representation is not working. You need to specify the characters as literals, `grep "[^ -~]" test.txt` will work.

Comment: `$ ls "Program Files"\\Git\\mingw64\\bin | grep 'grep'
bzegrep*
bzfgrep*
bzgrep*
x86_64-w64-mingw32-agrep.exe*
xzegrep*
xzfgrep*
xzgrep*`

Comment: Also, try `grep -P "[^[:ascii:]]"` if you need to print any line that has non-ASCII symbol.

Comment: `$ grep -P '[^[:ascii:]]' test.csv
3,CCCÆ,,ttt`
This works, thanks! Any idea on why what you rightly pointed out as hex range doesn't work?

Comment: It appears grep for windows does not support this hex representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the POSIX BRE and ERE syntax in grep for Windows do not support `\xXX` notation.

You may use `-P` option to enable the PCRE regex engine and then use

```
grep -P "[^\x{00}-\x{7E}]" file
```

Or,

```
grep -P "[^[:ascii:]]" file
```

to find any line containing a non-ASCII character.

**NOTE** that you cannot use `[^\x20-\x7E]` range because the CR (part of the line ending in Windows text files) will get matched, and all lines but the last (if it is not followed with trailing line break(s)) will get matched. You may add CR symbol though to the negated character class and use `grep -P "[^\x{0D}\x{20}-\x{7E}]" file` though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use directly perl, this would do :

```
perl -ne  'print if (/[^\x00-\x7F]/)' test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works. However, I do have a requirement to use `grep` for this. :(

Comment: Can you update your grep ? mine is "grep (GNU grep) 3.3" which works.

Comment: On Windows10, the default is `grep (GNU grep) 3.1` via MINGW64 and I'm actually interested in finding out why this does not work in this particular case if it could be helped.